# Echo custom attribute with getResource() ->getAttribute

Tags: product, attributes, custom-attributes

I'm trying to show all available sizes for one product on `list.phtml`

I've set up a custom attribute `size_age` (id:142) but when I try use the code

```
$attributeLabel = $customer->getResource() ->getAttribute('size_age') ->getFrontend() ->getAttribute() ->getFrontendLabel();
```

I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getResource() on null

---

**UPDATE**:

thank you for your answers. I changed the code to:

```
$attributeLabel = $_product->getResource() ->getAttribute('size_age') ->getFrontend() ->getAttribute() ->getFrontendLabel();
```

I dont have any error right now.

But I dont get any output. I'm trying to echo all available sizes for the product.

Comment: $customer is wrong,it should be product object

Comment: What is your `$customer` variable ? Shouldn't it be a `$product` variable ?

Comment: It should be `$_product`, NOT `$customer `

Comment: Please share more code?

Comment: thank you for your answers. I changed the code like you said and I dont have any error right now. But I dont get any output. I'm trying to echo all available sizes for the product

Answer (score 4):

You can get the value of custom attribute using following:

```
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('custom_attribute_code');
if ($attribute) {
    echo $attribute_value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
}
```